# Unknown bike parts

Tags: build

I just purchased a bike online and recieved it yesterday.  It has a few parts that I was hoping someone could help identify.

I'm not sure what any of these are, but the two rings are metallic:
[image]

I have no idea what these two plastic things and strap are for:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bottom picture is toe clips and associated straps.  The top picture shows and derailleur hanger (the hook shaped thing).  My best guess on the 2 black rings are headset spacers. The little nut is the only thing I'm not sure about.

Comment: The 'Nut' is a chainring bolt.

Comment: @Benzo Is it a bolt, or a spacer that the bolt would thread into?

Comment: There were some spacers already on the headset when I installed the handlebars, but they were plastic.  Are the plastic ones only there for protection and should be replaced with the metal ones?

Comment: I'm not at my bike right now, but I'm assuming the derailleur hanger (the derailleur is attached and seems to be functioning properly) and chainring bolt are spares?

Comment: @smoore - It would be odd for such "spares" to be provided with a new bike.  (And especially odd for the the toe clips to be provided, given that often bikes are sold without pedals and few people use toe clips anymore.)

Comment: @Kibbee - The appearance is consistent with a chainring bolt and "nut", screwed together.  See [this image](http://www.competitivecyclist.com/images/items/900/PSL/PSL0005/BK.jpg)

Comment: If the rings are metal, they could also be bottom bracket spacers, though that's unlikely as a spare.

Comment: The round metal disc is a quarter, specifially a Georgia state quarter, minted in 1999.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - It's a BikesDirect bike, which I think all come with pedals, and looking back I remember that they do come with toe clips.  As for the chainring bolt, there's only one of them, if it wasn't a spare wouldn't I need a lot more than that?  I haven't checked for missing chainring bolts, but it seems like it would be odd to install all but 1.

Comment: @smoore - It is possible that they assembled parts of the bike (eg, added your choice of crankset) and the chainring bolt was left over from, eg, a poly pack of 5 when your spider only uses 4.  Likewise the derailer hanger could be one of two supplied with the frame, varying based on the rear derailer configuration.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Ah, that would make sense.

Comment: The small chrome nut and bolt is likely the mounting bolt that attaches the derailleur hanger to the frame

Comment: I still think it's probably a chainring bolt, Just so happens that it can be repurposed in this case to hold the derailleur hanger in place. Pictures on bikes direct seem to show it used such. Many dawes and gravity brand bikes have this style hanger.